# How to plot grad(f(x,y))?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, gradient, sympy

I want to calculate and plot a gradient of any scalar function of two variables. If you really want a concrete example, lets say f=x^2+y^2 where x goes from -10 to 10 and same for y. How do I calculate and plot grad(f)? The solution should be vector and I should see vector lines. I am new to python so please use simple words.

EDIT:

@Andras Deak: thank you for your post, i tried what you suggested and instead of your test function (fun=3*x^2-5*y^2) I used function that i defined as V(x,y); this is how the code looks like but it reports an error

```
import numpy as np
import math 
import sympy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def V(x,y):
    t=[]
    for k in range (1,3): 
        for l in range (1,3):
            t.append(0.000001*np.sin(2*math.pi*k*0.5)/((4*(math.pi)**2)* (k**2+l**2)))  
            term = t* np.sin(2 * math.pi * k * x/0.004) * np.cos(2 * math.pi * l * y/0.004)
            return term 
    return term.sum()

x,y=sympy.symbols('x y')
fun=V(x,y)
gradfun=[sympy.diff(fun,var) for var in (x,y)]
numgradfun=sympy.lambdify([x,y],gradfun)

X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(-10,11),np.arange(-10,11))
graddat=numgradfun(X,Y)
plt.figure()
plt.quiver(X,Y,graddat[0],graddat[1])
plt.show()

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

And lets say I remove sin, I get another error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Mul'
```

I read tutorial for sympy and it says "The real power of a symbolic computation system such as SymPy is the ability to do all sorts of computations symbolically". I get this, I just dont get why I cannot multiply x and y symbols with float numbers.

What is the way around this? :( Help please!

**UPDATE**

@Andras Deak: I wanted to make things shorter so I removed many constants from the original formulas for V(x,y) and Cn*Dm. As you pointed out, that caused the sin function to always return 0 (i just noticed). Apologies for that. I will update the post later today when i read your comment in details. Big thanks!

**UPDATE 2**
I changed coefficients in my expression for voltage and this is the result:

[image: plot]

It looks good except that the arrows point in the opposite direction (they are supposed to go out of the reddish dot and into the blue one). Do you know how I could change that? And if possible, could you please tell me the way to increase the size of the arrows? I tried what was suggested in another topic ([Computing and drawing vector fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342072/computing-and-drawing-vector-fields)):

```
skip = (slice(None, None, 3), slice(None, None, 3))
```

This plots only every third arrow and matplotlib does the autoscale but it doesnt work for me (nothing happens when i add this, for any number that i enter)
You were already of huge help , i cannot thank you enough!

Comment: So what's the problem here? Gradient calculation, representation of 4D data using 2D monitor?

Comment: I know how to plot 2D function in python. But i dont know how to calculate and plot vector function that is the gradient of that scalar function (so, grad(V)= dV/dx * ex + dV/dy * ey, where ex and ey are ort vectors)

Comment: I added the [tag:python] and [tag:numpy] tags, next time make sure to include these. If you disagree, feel free to change/revert, it just seemed quicker this way. Now that I think of it: probably it should be more [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), less numpy... If you figure out how to compute the gradient, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678843/evaluate-sympy-expression-from-an-array-of-values) can help you use that function for plotting.

Comment: What about automatic differentiation in Python? Here is the package which looks good https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ad/

Comment: your last link confused me. that topic doesnt say anything about plotting (they talk about numerical evaluation as far as i understood it)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using `sympy` and `numpy`. This is the first time I use sympy, so others will/could probably come up with much better and more elegant solutions.

```
import sympy

#define symbolic vars, function
x,y=sympy.symbols('x y')
fun=3*x**2-5*y**2

#take the gradient symbolically
gradfun=[sympy.diff(fun,var) for var in (x,y)]

#turn into a bivariate lambda for numpy
numgradfun=sympy.lambdify([x,y],gradfun)
```

now you can use `numgradfun(1,3)` to compute the gradient at `(x,y)==(1,3)`. This function can then be used for plotting, which you said you can do.

For plotting, you can use, for instance, `matplotlib`'s `quiver`, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(-10,11),np.arange(-10,11))
graddat=numgradfun(X,Y)

plt.figure()
plt.quiver(X,Y,graddat[0],graddat[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

### UPDATE

You added a specification for your function to be computed. It contains the product of terms depending on `x` and `y`, which seems to break my above solution. I managed to come up with a new one to suit your needs. However, your function seems to make little sense. From your edited question:

```
t.append(0.000001*np.sin(2*math.pi*k*0.5)/((4*(math.pi)**2)* (k**2+l**2)))
term = t* np.sin(2 * math.pi * k * x/0.004) * np.cos(2 * math.pi * l * y/0.004)
```

On the other hand, from your corresponding comment to this answer:

> V(x,y) = Sum over n and m of [Cn * Dm * sin(2pinx) * cos(2pimy)]; sum goes from -10 to 10; Cn and Dm are coefficients, and i calculated
>   that CkDl = sin(2pik)/(k^2 +l^2) (i used here k and l as one of the
>   indices from the sum over n and m).

I have several problems with this: both `sin(2*pi*k)` and `sin(2*pi*k/2)` (the two competing versions in the prefactor are always zero for integer `k`, giving you a constant zero `V` at every `(x,y)`. Furthermore, in your code you have magical frequency factors in the trigonometric functions, which are missing from the comment. If you multiply your `x` by `4e-3`, you *drastically* change the spatial dependence of your function (by changing the wavelength by roughly a factor of a thousand). So you should really decide what your function is.

So here's a solution, where I assumed

> V(x,y)=sum_{k,l = 1 to 10} C_{k,l} * sin(2*pi*k*x)*cos(2*pi*l*y), with
>   C_{k,l}=sin(2*pi*k/4)/((4*pi^2)*(k^2+l^2))*1e-6

This is a combination of your various versions of the function, with the modification of `sin(2*pi*k/4)` in the prefactor in order to have a non-zero function. I expect you to be able to fix the numerical factors to your actual needs, after you figure out the proper mathematical model.

So here's the full code:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def CD(k,l):
    #return sp.sin(2*sp.pi*k/2)/((4*sp.pi**2)*(k**2+l**2))*1e-6
    return sp.sin(2*sp.pi*k/4)/((4*sp.pi**2)*(k**2+l**2))*1e-6

def Vkl(x,y,k,l):
    return CD(k,l)*sp.sin(2*sp.pi*k*x)*sp.cos(2*sp.pi*l*y)

def V(x,y,kmax,lmax):
    k,l=sp.symbols('k l',integers=True)
    return sp.summation(Vkl(x,y,k,l),(k,1,kmax),(l,1,lmax))


#define symbolic vars, function
kmax=10
lmax=10
x,y=sp.symbols('x y')
fun=V(x,y,kmax,lmax)

#take the gradient symbolically
gradfun=[sp.diff(fun,var) for var in (x,y)]

#turn into bivariate lambda for numpy
numgradfun=sp.lambdify([x,y],gradfun,'numpy')
numfun=sp.lambdify([x,y],fun,'numpy')

#plot
X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10,10,51),np.linspace(-10,10,51))
graddat=numgradfun(X,Y)
fundat=numfun(X,Y)

hf=plt.figure()
hc=plt.contourf(X,Y,fundat,np.linspace(fundat.min(),fundat.max(),25))
plt.quiver(X,Y,graddat[0],graddat[1])
plt.colorbar(hc)
plt.show()
```

I defined your `V(x,y)` function using some auxiliary functions for transparence. I left the summation cut-offs as literal parameters, `kmax` and `lmax`: in your code these were 3, in your comment they were said to be 10, and anyway they should be infinity.

The gradient is taken the same way as before, but when converting to a numpy function using `lambdify` you have to set an additional string parameter, `'numpy'`. This will alow the resulting numpy lambda to accept array input (essentially it will use `np.sin` instead of `math.sin` and the same for `cos`).

I also changed the definition of the grid from `array` to `np.linspace`: this is usually more convenient. Since your function is almost constant at integer grid points, I created a denser mesh for plotting (51 points while keeping your original limits of (-10,10) fixed).

For clarity I included a few more plots: a `contourf` to show the value of the function (contour lines should always be orthogonal to the gradient vectors), and a colorbar to indicate the value of the function. Here's the result:

[image]

The composition is obviously not the best, but I didn't want to stray too much from your specifications. The arrows in this figure are actually hardly visible, but as you can see (and also evident from the definition of `V`) your function is periodic, so if you plot the same thing with smaller limits and less grid points, you'll see more features and larger arrows.

Comment: why numgradfun(1,3)? i want gradient in every point of x and y. I do know how to plot scalar function, however i do not know how to plot vector function with those tiny arrows

Comment: uhh. so to be sure, you calculated and plotted grad(3*x^2-5*y^2) for every x and y in a range from -10 to 11?

Comment: On [-10,11), i.e. the intervals are open on the side of 11 (otherwise: yes). I strongly recommend looking at the help of the methods involved; you should preferably never use code that you do not understand. Why I'm saying this is that it's very basic `python` that `range(1,3)` will give you `[1,2]`.

Comment: First NumPy answer? Nice to see you jumping in here!

Comment: @Divakar, indeed, thank you! And I've never used sympy before either, it was fun learning the very basics on the fly:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Exactly and the rush to learn and answer at the sametime, it's crazy good!

Comment: I edited the top comment and added the code, please take a look and let me know if you know how to fix it

Comment: @dota, this is half a new question. One of the problems is that your `V(x,y)` is a numerical function rather than symbolic. Then if it *was* symbolic, you'd need `sympy.sin`, but then `append` will throw an error. You'd have to define your function symbolically, which probably involves just a bit of thinking. Anyway: you have 2 `return`s in your function, so I'd be surprised if the function returned what you think it returned.

Comment: ah okay, ill try to figure out how to define it symbolically. about return in my function, i simply want a sum of all terms, but if i try to use one return, i get some nonsense/errors. i will think about that some other time (im an absolute beginner and it will take me hours to figure it out), right now i have to solve this symbol thingy. thank you for your help

Comment: @dota, if you specify in clear terms what your function V(x,y) should look like, mathematically speaking, I *might* try to figure it out for you, when I find the time.

Comment: so its electric potential as a function of x and y, and I did plane wave expansion: V(x,y) = Sum over n and m of [Cn*Dm * sin(2pinx) * cos(2pimy)]; sum goes from -10 to 10, both for n and m; Cn and Dm are coefficients, and i calculated that Ck*Dl = sin(2pik)/(k^2 +l^2) (i used here k and l as one of the indices from the sum over n and m). I removed unimportant constants copared to the code above. I realise it sounds a bit complicated but its simple on the paper. thank you again so much. Ill be thinking about the solution in the meantime

Comment: @dota see my updated answer. Quite a few things are unclear, but that's a maths thing, and you should be able to figure it out. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dota, the gradient of a function will always point from the minimum towards the maximum. But the electric field is `E=-grad(V)`, so if your function is voltage then the *negative* gradient is the electric field. Just plot the negative gradient, and your arrow directions will fix. As for the scaling: what you linked only made use of automatic scaling. For you it might be more straightforward to generate 2 meshes: one for the contour, and a rarer for the quiver. [Here's the manual](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver) for using the parameter `scale` in quiver.

Comment: you are of course right. I also managed to make "skip" work . thank you again for all your help!